# No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags'

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I have been breaking my head over this for a full day but can't figure out the problem. It happened after I copied my Django project from one PC to another.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/saitohiromasa/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_summernote/admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget, SummernoteInplaceWidget
  File "/Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_summernote/widgets.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags'
```

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_summernote',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'blogs.apps.BlogsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

My Django version is 3.0
What might be wrong here ? Please help me out. Much thanks!

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.0

Comment: https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/issues/381

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags` was [removed in version 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#features-removed-in-3-0)

> The staticfiles and admin_static template tag libraries are removed.

The `django-summernote` package has not been updated since January and does not support Django 3

Comment: It has been updated and now works with Django 3.x

Answer (score 40):

I'll leave this here just in case other people end up in this question to fix django 3 function location change.

It seems like in django 3, static templatetag is moved among builtin template tags.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static

https://github.com/django/django/blob/50cf183d219face91822c75fa0a15fe2fe3cb32d/django/templatetags/static.py#L162

So instead of importing it from here: `from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static`, you need to import it from here: `from django.templatetags.static import static`

Comment: Thank you. I will also try this !

Answer (score 12):

This is going to be pretty common for a while as everyone starts to move into Django 3 over the next few years.

In addition to the accepted answer, this is what I've been adding to support both Django 2 and Django 3 `static` imports (esp. helpful with managing packages)

```
try:
    # Django 2
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # Django 3
    from django.templatetags.static import static
```

Answer (score 0):

check the commas in the list of installed apps
one comma can ruin your life

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).